# Is there a way to change the path from /_tmp in pnpm?

Tags: docker, pnpm

So I'm using docker with pterodactyl panel and it seems to make the file system at / read only, but not in the users home directory. I am using a custom docker image that uses pnpm + alpine and node and it tries to link files to a temporary folder at /_tmp and a bunch of random numbers. I'm wondering if there's a way to change that path because I'm pretty sure I can't make it non-read-only due to limitations with pterodactyl.

Here's the error i got:

```
 ERROR  EROFS: read-only file system, link '/home/container/_tmp_7_c1f222fdf43b255284b8bee04ecacc6a'-> '/_tmp_7_1c18c3daae49ad638be3373704cb73a1'
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ pnpm update check failed │
│ Try running with sudo or get access │
│ to the local update config store via │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Here's the link to the docker image: https://github.com/creepinson/pnpm-docker

Comment: This probably happens when pnpm tries to find a location for the global store. Try to specify the location of the global store explicitly, by setting the store-dir setting. E.g. `pnpm install --store-dir=/path/to/store-dir`

Comment: might be good to file an issue in the pnpm repo about it